# Adding/using parameter completion support for Ensime

Tags: scala, emacs, ensime

When using Ensime (specificially in Emacs for me, although I suspect this question applies to other Ensime integrations), I often miss the support provided by IntelliJ for parameter completion - that is, when entering a methods parameters, you can use a shortcut key to show the names and types of those parameters, as a memory aid, as opposed to looking them up in ScalaDoc or such.

I've several times accidentally got Ensime to do this for me, but I'm not sure under what circumstances it works, or what key binding is actually invoking it.

If it's an autocomplete, then perhaps someone knows the name of the defn it's using, so I can bind it to a key?

I've dug into the Ensime source, but can't seem to find this.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. Have you been able to come up with a solution?

Comment: same [here](https://github.com/dragos/dragos-vscode-scala/issues/39)